# Jquery how to unclick() element?

Tags: jquery

I have a table which has lots of `<td></td>`. what i want to do is add CSS to the `<td>` when it got clicked, and remove the CSS from that `<td>` when user click other `<td>`, how can i implement that?  Thanks.

Comment: lots of periods and click other commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var lastTD;
$('td').click(function(){
    if (lastTD) lastTD.removeClass('some-class');
    lastTD = $(this).addClass('some-class');
});
```

CSS:

```
.some-class { color: red; ... }
```

Comment: * It's fragile.
* It creates a global variable it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
// For click on an element
$('#element_id').click(function() {//or class or any selector
 //change css class
 });
// For outside of an element
$('body').click(function() {
 //change css class
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$('td').removeClass('active')
$(this).addClass('active')
```

i.e. you remove the active class from all td; then add that class to a specific one.

Comment: I'm assuming this goes goes inside an event handler? -- if so, the first selection `$('td')` is very wasteful (selecting all TDs every time a single TD is clicked, and then removing a class from ALL TDs even though only one of them has the class!?)

Comment: I agree as this was just an example because author didn't specify anything.

If the number of TDs is small (less than hundred, I'd say) it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like event delegation to capture clicks on the entire table and remove the class.

```
$('#my-table').click(function(event) {
    $(this).find('td').removeClass('clicked');
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('td')) {
        target.addClass('clicked');
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```